# Trying to render a v-data-table in a v-dialog does not work

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to implement a v-data-table in a v-dialog

```
  <v-dialog max-width = '600px' v-model = 'dialog'>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>
        <span class = "headline"> Reconstructor </span>
      </v-card-title>
    <draggable :list = "draggableList">
      <!--<div v-for = "(item, index) in draggableList" :key = "index">
        {{item.fieldValue}} , {{item.fieldName}}
      </div> -->
      <v-data-table :header = 'headersList' :items = 'draggableList'> 
      </v-data-table>
    </draggable>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
```

Even if i remove the draggable component nothing changes.
I manually verified the headersList and the draggableList and they are correct. Sorry if it is a begginer mistake but it is my first project in vue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, I just created a working code snippet below with the same code you posted in post. Can you please have a look and see if it helps.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: true,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.7/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.7/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-dialog max-width='600px' v-model='dialog'>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class = "headline"> Reconstructor </span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts">
        </v-data-table>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: The output is the one i would also like to have. Will try and see what i implemented wrong in my code.

Comment: Found the bug, i wrote ':header' instead of 'headers'. Thank you for the work and help offered.